# boxTidwell - error about positive values

Tags: r, r-car

I'm trying to do a boxTidwell function with the following form:

```
boxTidwell(y~x1+x2, data=dataframe)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in boxTidwell.default(y, X1, X2, max.iter = max.iter, tol = tol,  : 
the variables to be transformed must have only positive values
```

The only way I can interpret this is that it is telling me that some of my x values are <0. However, this is not true - I've checked.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: "must have only positive values" implies x values > 0, so negative values or zeroes would cause this error - do you possibly have some zeroes?

Comment: There are 0s in 6 of x2 :/ Would that cause a problem?

Comment: I see... I omitted the 0 values from x2 and it worked. Interesting... Thanks for the help man!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.